# How can I find what version of ruby an app was written for?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm using rvm on Ubuntu 12 to manage ruby versions/gemsets. I am testing various projects and some gems won't work with certain versions of Ruby or with each other. Is it possible to find which version of ruby an app was written for, so I can set my rvm to use that version and get the right gems when I run bundle install?

Comment: Most of the time im stuck searching through the CHANGELOG file on the gems GitHub repo looking for when they dropped support for certain versions. I'd try the latest ruby 2.1, and if you can't get it to run under that, move backward to 2.0 and 1.9.3 (and 1.8.7 if you're really desperate). I'd expect 1.9.3 to be most widely supported.

Comment: For the most part that seems to be the case. 1.9.3 seems to be the new "standard". I was mostly looking for which gems played nicely with each other, as my first experience led me to having to install earlier versions of gems in order to run some apps, but it seemed to be some missing libs outside of ruby that were causing my compile issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lookup the gems on rubygems.org. They are supposed to list what version of ruby they are compatible with, but that may not always be kept up to date.

If that doesn't narrow it down, you can check the gem's CHANGELOG file on github.

In the end, you may have to just try a few. There's only a handful of versions in common use, so it's not like you have to try then all.

in my experience ruby 1.9.3 is most widely supported at the time of this writing. Ruby 2.0 and 2.1 would also be good to try. 1.8.7 is pretty old and will likely give you a good bit of trouble, but it was the standard for a long time.

Comment: Good advice, I've tried a few versions and google gave me some good ideas as to where some of the inconsistencies are. I suppose looking at the age of the app since the last commit too would give me a better picture, I was just wondering if it was in a set place, as a lot of the emphasis on ruby was convention over configuration. But I suspect some of my issues may be more related to gcc anyway.